# How to put queue in a Python 2 BaseHTTPRequestHandler?

Tags: python, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

With Python 2.7, I have extended the BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler to support a do_POST method.  I would like to give the request handler a queue, so that it can put the posted data on a queue to be processed by another thread.

Here is a stripped down version of my class:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import json

class PostHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

        length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        self.post_data = self.rfile.read(length)

        try:
            if self.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
                self.post_data = json.loads(self.post_data)
                self.log_message(json.dumps(self.post_data))

                ### WANT TO PUT self.post_data ON A QUEUE HERE ###

        except KeyError as error:
            self.log_message('No Content-Type header')
        except ValueError as error:
            self.log_message("%s" % error)
```

Since then handler gets created by the BaseHTTPServer, I don't think I can alter the **init** method to pass in a queue.

I'd like my main() to look something like this:

```
def main():

    import logging
    import Queue
    import signal
    import threading
    import traceback


    try:
        # set stoprequest to accept Ctrl+c
        stoprequest = threading.Event()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signal, frame: stoprequest.set())

        args = _get_main_args()

        ### HERE IS THE QUEUE, HOW TO I GIVE A REFERENCE TO THE HANDLER??? ###
        data_queue = Queue.Queue()

        handler = PostHTTPRequestHandler

        server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer((args.address, args.port), handler)

        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        server_thread.daemon = True
        server_thread.start()

        while not stoprequest.is_set():

            try:
                data = data_queue.get(False)

                ### I WANT TO PROCESS THE DATA HERE ###

            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

        server.shutdown()

        #logging.debug("Exiting with return code 0")
        return 0

    except Exception:
        sys.stderr.write("%s" % traceback.format_exc())
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I now see that the init for the BaseRequestHandler looks like this:

```
class BaseRequestHandler:

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        self.request = request
        self.client_address = client_address
        self.server = server
        self.setup()
        try:
            self.handle()
        finally:
            self.finish()
```

So I will extend the BaseHTTPServer to contain a queue, then it will be available to the handler.

```
class QueuingHTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
        self.data_queue = Queue.Queue()
```

So now the handler looks like this:

```
class PostHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

        length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        self.post_data = self.rfile.read(length)

        try:
            if self.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
                self.post_data = json.loads(self.post_data)
                self.log_message(json.dumps(self.post_data))

                try:
                    self.server.data_queue.put(self.post_data)
                except Queue.Full:
                    pass

        except KeyError as error:
            self.log_message('No Content-Type header')
        except ValueError as error:
            self.log_message("%s" % error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code submitted by Josh to use a shared Queue reference instead of creating one during instantiation.

```
class QueuingHTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, data_queue, bind_and_activate=True):
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
        self.data_queue = queue
```